# Why is it sometimes called 1-consistency?

Tags: logic, terminology

$\Sigma_1$-soundness of a theory (meaning that every theorem it proves that is $\Sigma_1$ in the arithmetical hierarchy is true in the natural numbers) is sometimes called 1-consistency, which suggests that it is in a hierarchy of notions called $n$-consistency, with $n$ ranging over the natural numbers. Is there such a hierarchy, and if there is, is [$\omega$-consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory) some kind of limit of that hierarchy?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have read that article (and now I have linked to it in the question, which I should have done when I first wrote the question) but it says nothing about why it's called 1-consistency (it doesn't even mention that it's called 1-consistency).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Do you just mean that I messed up the arithmetical hierarchy? Corrected.

Comment: I remembered wrong. Wikipedia does mention that it's sometimes called 1-consistency, but not why.

Comment: See e.g Daniel Isaacson's lectures on [Godel's Incompleteness Theorems (2018)](https://courses-archive.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/38136): page 71 for **Denition 62 (1-consistency)** that is related to the "form" of the formula: $\Sigma_1$-formula $\exists v_iF(v_i)$ is a formula with *one* existential quantifier (old symbols related to Algebra of Logic: $\Sigma$ for existential and $\Pi$ for universal) and **Proposition 78 (1-consistency implies consistency)** and **Theorem 81 (equivalence of $\Sigma_1$-soundness and 1-consistency)**.

Comment: And see **Ch7.4 $\Sigma_0$-soundness and $\Sigma_1$-soundness** (page 67) for the first two definitions.

Comment: Basically the name derives from Gödel's original terminology: the original Gödel’s First Incompleteness Theorem was proved under assumption of ω-consistency of theory $T$; later has been showed that the proof only requires a special case of ω-consistency, called 1-consistency, meaning that the first-order theory T (with suitable language expressing basic arithmetic) is 1-consistent iff there exists no bounded formula $A(x)$ in which only x occurs free such that $T  \vdash ¬∀xA(x)$ and, for any natural number $k, T \vdash A(\overline k)$.

Comment: See also Bernd Buldt, [The Scope of Gödel’s First Incompleteness Theorem (2014)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11787-014-0107-3) **3.1. Consistency and 1-Soundness**: Godel used ω-consistency, which is a stronger assumption than simple consistency. This is why we ask the question: How much consistency is required for establishing GIT?

Comment: According to Kreisel's original defintion ([1957, page 109)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2964108), we have $n$-consistency, where $n$ is the number of quantifiers in the prefix, and we have that $\omega$-consistency is $n$-consistency, for every $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Daniel Isaacson's lectures on the Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems](https://courses-archive.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/38136) (which Mauro Allegranza linked in a comment) mention that $n$-consistency is defined as $\omega$-consistency with respect to $\Sigma_n$-sentences and that this terminology, or at least 1-consistency, was introduced by Kreisel.